# two real gdp at the same price level in ad as model

Tags: macroeconomics, supply-and-demand, keynesian-economics, aggregate-demand, aggregate-supply

in a macro book of arnold i see an agg demand-supply model where it seems above the equilibrium price level there are two real gdp for the same price level. the book then goes on to explain that there is less demand and more supply so there is a surplus. This sounds utterly nonsensical to me, as if this isnt macroeconomics but micro. I might be missing something trivial, any ideas?